# Access html files / video files outside htdocs folder

Tags: php, linux

Trying to protect video files that are done in camtsia which outputs html/with flash embed video files.

Not sure how I would access them using PHP. I've searched stackoverflow and found using alias would be an option? Is that still secure though? Is that the best way to go? Or should I try to purue a file open operations using PHP.

It needs to serve an html page which has .js .swf files along in the same protected dir.

Any help or direction is appreciated.

Comment: How do you mean protect? Prevent users from downloading them?

Comment: yes protect from downloading them

Comment: But don't you want the users to the website to be able to download them as they view the site (so the site works!)?

Comment: I guess I should say prevent direct access vs. protect from downloading otherwise the videos wont work. I get your point :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use readfile to access the file and the header function to forge the content. Make sure the www-data user, which is the Apache user and PHP uses it to access the filsystem, has permission on that folder.

```
header('Content-type: video/avi');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="videodownload.avi"');
readfile('/var/videos/myvideo.avi');
```

Comment: Interesting, in my case its a html file that houses the video, swf, .js files. So I assume I would change the content type to html to read the html file

Comment: Erm, no. Since the user would be able to view the HTML source and grab the video. If you want to display the video in a Flash player or HTML5 video player, you can't protect it. Period, unfortunately.

Comment: This method only works for protecting files from being accessed directly from the public_html folder, therefore, the browser. This way, you can use PHP to serve the files and, of course, apply any rules before doing so. Like password, rights, etc. However, it won't work for serving video players, etc.